# Relocating the Chromium unpacking directory

Tags: jxbrowser

As the title states, is it possible to relocate where JXBrowser unpacks its Chromium package, and have it reference from there?

SSD concerns and all that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change binaries directory using system property `jxbrowser.chromium.dir` as described here: https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000015146-chromium-binaries